# router.get not posting multiple params

Tags: node.js, express

Hi so I am learning basics of node.js and express, and I was trying to submit a form with two parameters and trying to get that in the same screen.
But for some reason I guess I am not sure how to use router.get to get the both input fields parameters.
Here is my js file

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/:awesomeTitle?/:awesomeAuthor?', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('node',
    {title: req.params.awesomeTitle ? req.params.awesomeTitle : '' , author: req.params.awesomeAuthor ? req.params.awesomeAuthor : '' });
});

router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
    var awesomeTitle = req.body.title;
    var awesomeAuthor = req.body.author;
    res.redirect('/' + awesomeTitle + awesomeAuthor);
});

module.exports = router;
```

And here is my hbs file.

```
<h1> Result </h1>
<h2>{{author}}</h2>
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<form action="/" method="post">
<input type="text"/ name="title">
<input type="text"/ name="author">
<button type="submit">Submit</submit>
</form>
```

So just wanted to know how to get the awesome title and author from submit to the page again in the h1 and h2 tags.
P.S I am not sure how to debug this application so.. and it doesn't show any errors, all I get is both the input fields answer combined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're missing a `/` in your redirect. Try changing the last line in your post handler to this:

```
res.redirect('/' + awesomeTitle + '/' + awesomeAuthor);
```

Comment: Thank you!!! 
I was actualy thinking that while writing the code, since I am a php developer so I thought that might be the way, but then again I thought since I never used node, it might be something new :D But thanks alot!